# Regular Expression: How to replace a string that does NOT start with something?

Tags: regex

I need to replace a root relative URL with a different root relative URL:

```
/Images/filename.jpg
```

should be replaced with:

```
/new/images-dir/filename.jpg
```

I started by using PHP's [`str_replace`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) function:

```
$newText = str_replace('/Images/', '/new/images-dir/', $text);
```

...but then I realized that it was replacing my absolute URLs that I **don't** want replaced:

```
http://sub.domain.com/something/Images/filename.jpg
#...is being replaced with...
http://sub.domain.com/something/new/images-dir/filename.jpg
```

So then I switched to using PHP's [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) function so I can use a regular expression to selectively replace only the root relative URLs and not the absolute URLs. However, I can't seem to figure out the syntax to do this:

```
$text = 'There is a root relative URL here: <img src="/Images/filename.jpg">'
      . 'and an absolute here: <img src="http://sub.domain.com/something/Images/filename.jpg">'
      . 'and one not in quotes: /Images/filename.jpg';
$newText = preg_replace('#/Images/#', '/new/images-dir/', $text);
```

How can I write my regular expression so that it ignores any absolute URLs and only replaces the root relative URLs?

Comment: What about `<img src="foo/Images/filename.jpg">`? Should that also be replaced?

Answer (score 2):

After taking *three* edits to come up with a correct regex, I concluded that my first answer was best. [PHP's string functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php) are better suited than regular expressions for this task:

**Using str_replace():**

```
function match($value)
{
   // The second condition is probably unnecessary,
   // unless your path argument is incorrectly formatted
   if( ($value[0] != "/") || (stristr($value, "http:") != FALSE) )
   {
      return $value;
   }
   return str_replace("/Images/", "/new/images-dir/", $value);
}
```

The advantage of [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) is readability.

If the reader doesn't understand regular expressions, they can still clearly see criteria for matching: the input string must begin with '/' and must not contain *"http:"*.

Furthermore, both the search key and replacement string are clearly represented in plain-text.

**Using preg_replace():**

```
function match($value)
{
   $pattern = "/^(\/((.+?)\/)*?)Images\//";

   // Assuming value is a root-relative path, everything
   // before "Images/" should be capured into back-reference 1;
   // The replacement string re-inserts it before "new/images-dir/"
   return preg_replace($pattern, "\\1new/images-dir/", $value);
}
```

The regular expression tries to match following:

1. Match the beginning of string with `^`,
2. followed by a forward slash to indicate root-relative URL,
3. followed by zero-or-more [lazily quantified](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Lazy_quantification) repetitions of the
   group `((.+?)/)`. This group consists of one-or-more lazily quantified characters, and another forward-slash.
4. Match subsequent string *"Images"* and final forward-slash.

Both `match()` functions operate the same when tested as follows:

```
match("http://test/more/Images/file"); // Returns original argument
match("/test/more/Images/file");       // Returns with match replaced
```

Comment: Do a search for inverse lookup w/regex. or Reverse matching. That should work for you, there are plenty of questions about it on SO.

Comment: For example - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word

Comment: @Andrew: Sorry for all the edits, it works now. And thanks for the correction... it seems square brackets are reserved for character classes, which have special syntax, and only match a single character.

Answer (score 1):

Root-relative links generally are within quotes, as you've shown. So match on the quote and put it back in the replacement.

```
$text = 'There is a root relative image here: <img src="/Images/filename.jpg">';
$newText = preg_replace('#"/Images/#', '"/new/images-dir/', $text);
```

**Update**

If you have two different cases, try two different and *specific* replaces rather than trying to engineer one perfect one. Let us know what the other case(s) are.

If you need to match more than that, then you are looking for a "negative lookbehind assertion" so you make sure that it doesn't match the "http://blah" part before it.  The problem with lookbehind is that it requires a static string match... it can't have variable length. http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php

Something like this might work, if you mostly use links to .net and .com links and the Images part is at the root:

```
$text = 'There is a root relative image here: <img src="/Images/filename.jpg">';
$newText = preg_replace('#(?<=.net|.com|.org|.cc)/Images/#', '/new/images-dir/', $text);
```

Comment: You are correct, that would work, but there are places that I also need to match that aren't in quotes.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [PHP documentation on Lookbehind assertions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php):

> Lookbehind assertions start with `(?<=` for positive assertions and `(?<!` for negative assertions.

Using this syntax, I was able to get this to work:

```
$text = preg_replace('#(?<!http\://sub.domain.com/something)/Images/#', '/new/images-dir/', $text);
```

Comment: That is what I was posting. ;-) Just be sure that you only have full links to that one `sub.domain.com`. You can use `|` alternations in it but nothing like `.*` that matches variable length data.